# Как отобразить блок поверх видео и псевдоэлемента

Tags: html, css

```css
.video {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.video_media {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.intro {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.intro:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <video class="video_media" src="video/video.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
</div>


/* Этот блок мне нужно наложить поверх видео
<div class="header_text">
  <div class="header_text_one"></div>
  <div class="header_text_two"></div>
</div>
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Заварачиваете всё это дело в

```css
.video_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.header_text {
  position: absolute: top:50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="video_wrapper">
  <div class="video">
    <video class="video_media" src="video/video.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
  <div class="header_text">
    <div class="header_text_one"></div>
    <div class="header_text_two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

и будет у вас поверх. С видео конечно вы работать не сможете, но эт уже второй вопрос)